# WSO2 API-manager returns 500 internal server error

Tags: wso2-api-manager, http-status-code-500, ibm-api-management, undocumented-behavior

I'm trying to use WSO2 to manage some APIs, i followed all the steps in the documentation, everything seems good until i tried invoke my first API that i've deployed on production, unfortunately it doesn't work, it returns "undocumented error" as shown in the capture below :
[capture of the error in the tryout section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns5Yi.png)

for information, i deployed wso2 on kubernetes with one node for gateways and another for control planes.
[deployment architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgdTB.png)

Comment: Just type the url in the browser and accept the certificate. Then you can access the API

Comment: @Pubci I tried this option and still not working, it gives me a 500 http error as the following : 500 Internal Server Error  openresty/1.15.8.2